# How to display attached USB devices with drive letter using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am attempting to list all connected usb devices using powershell. While I am able to display the devices using the following command, I cannot get the drive letter to show up, Is there a way to make that happen?

```
GET-WMIOBJECT win32_diskdrive | Where { $_.InterfaceType –eq ‘USB’ }
```

The output is as follows:

```
Partitions : 1
DeviceID   : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
Model      : Corsair Voyager VEGA USB Device
Size       : 61944583680
Caption    : Corsair Voyager VEGA USB Device
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this will do it:

```
gwmi cim_logicaldisk | ? drivetype -eq 2
```

According to [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx) DriveType 2 is removable disk.